# how to remove compare products from sidebar?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, xml, html

Actually i am very new to magento 
I want to remove "Compare Products" block from side bar, there are some solutions given in google to edit in \app\design\frontend\default\beautyshop\layout\local.xml file but in my case there is no local.xml file exist in the  "layout" folder, although i create an local.xml file and put the code

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
    </default>
</layout>
```

but still it not works for me i am totally stuck what to do any help is really appreciable.

Comment: Did you purge the layout cache after making this change?

Comment: what does mean by purge the layout cache, does it mean to refresh the cache storage management ? yes i refresh the cache storage management.

Answer (score 1):

I use following construction `<remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" /`> If it will not work, try to remove smth which 100% exist on page (for example header)

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  You are using a handle instead of referencing a block.

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <!-- either "left" or "right" -->
        <reference name="left">
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Removing sets the ignore flag, meaning it cannot come back once you have set that flag.  Instead, just unset the child.  That way you can move it around if need be.